# Laravel tables relations issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am new with Laravel, I have two tables users and roles related via pivot table `role_user` but I deleted pivot table and put foreign key `id_role` in table `user` but I need also to change this code but I find some problems.

```
@if(!empty($user->roles))
    @foreach($user->roles as $v)
        <label class="label label-success">{{ $v->display_name }}</label>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please update your question with the relations defined in `User` and `Role` models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User model :

```
class User extends Model {

  public function roles()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Roles::class);
  }
```

Role migration file :

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('todolists')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

Role model :

```
class Role extends Model {

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

}
```

now you can do this :

```
@if(!empty($user->roles))
    @foreach($user->roles as $v)
        <label class="label label-success">{{ $v->display_name }}</label>
    @endforeach
@endif
```